# Bcrypt with graphQL and nestJS

Tags: graphql, nestjs, bcrypt

In NestJS and GraphQL while using Bcrypt I had to use it with promise like below

```
async getUser(email: String, password: String) {
    let user: User[] | User | null = await this.userModel.find({ email });
    user = user.length && user[0];

    if (user) {
      return bcrypt
        .compare(password, user.password)
        .then((res: any) => {
          if (res) {
            return { result: true, message: 'Logged in successfully.'};
          } else return { result: false, message: 'Incorrect Password.' };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return { result: false, message: err.message };
        });
    } else {
      return { result: false, message: 'User not found. Try Sign-up!' };
    }
  }
```

otherwise, if I was using it in a normal fashion like below

```
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, result) {
    // result == true
});
```

it was throwing an error like
`"Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.getUser."`

Does anyone know why this behavior?

Comment: It's because `bcrypt.compare` is async. You could also `await` the result. Also beware that you're allowing multiple users with the same email address so you may be matching the password with the wrong user.

Comment: Hoo, okay so then we were receiving a promise object which was not the type we were expecting so was getting the error right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily use [compareSync](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#to-check-a-password-1) to synchronize

```
// Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compareSync(myPlaintextPassword, hash); // true
bcrypt.compareSync(someOtherPlaintextPassword, hash); // false
```